# Converting php array of arrays into single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array whose values are all arrays of a specific format that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
           (
               [username] => John
           )    
    [1] => Array
           (
               [username] => Joe
           )
    [2] => Array
           (
               [username] => Jake
           )
)
```

and I would like to have this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John   
    [1] => Joe
    [2] => Jake
)
```

I can do this manually with a loop but is there a better way? If not, is it possible to do this for an array of objects that have a common attribute?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since PHP 5.5.0 there is a built-in function [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which does exactly this.

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.3 or 5.4, you can always use [this library](http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/07/the-array-column-php-userland-library/) [(open-source)](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).

Comment: How can i use array_column if i have no specific keys for my array. Its the default keys provided in php

Comment: Since PHP 5.6 you can use: `$newArray = array_merge(...$oldArray);`

Answer (score 33):

why complicate things?

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    $new[$k] = $v['username'];
}
```

Comment: and this is faster than array_map()

Answer (score 12):

Since PHP 5.6 you can use the splat operator. In case array keys are numeric, you could use this:

```
$newArray = array_merge(...$oldArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$new_array = array_column($last_array, 'username');
```

Answer (score 5):

For other readers, like myself, if the key `username` is different for each internal array, and you want to flatten it, use this:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $the_array);
```

Note that the keys have to be different. Like this:

```
[
 0 => [
  'a' => 1
 ],
 1 => [
  'b' => 2
 ]
]
```

After running the code, you have this:

```
[
 'a' => 1,
 'b' => 2,
]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP 5.3 you can make use of `array_walk_recursive` and a closure (the closure can be replaced by a normal function if your PHP version < 5.3):

```
function arrayFlatten(array $array) {
    $flatten = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($value) use(&$flatten) {
        $flatten[] = $value;
    });

    return $flatten;
}

$nested = array(
    array('username' => 'John'),
    array('username' => 'Joe'),
    array('username' => 'Jake'),
);

$flattened = arrayFlatten($nested);

var_dump($flattened)

array
  0 => string 'John' (length=4)
  1 => string 'Joe' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Jake' (length=4)
```

Comment: The function arrayFlatten(array $array) should be arrayFlatten(array $nested).

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = array_map(create_function('$auser', 'return $auser["username"];'), $array);
```

If using objects you could just change `return $auser["username"];` to `return $auser->get_username();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach   ($arr as $key => $val)
{
    sort($val );
    $new = array_merge($val, $new);
}
print_r ($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$list=array();
foreach($array as $v) {
    array_push($list, $v['username']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the keys:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $v) {

    $new_array[] = $v['username']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who're using `composer`:

1. if <=php5.5 `array_column` can be used
2. if >php5.5 available polyfills such as https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/tree/master/src/Php55 can be used. Once you `composer install symfony/polyfill-php55`, then you can just call `array_column` as if your php5.4 or below had it.