# Convert array of array to array key value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array in php.  I tried to convert some result

My code

```
for($la=0;$la < count($finaldata); $la++)
     { 
     
     ------------------
     -------------------
        $data_final2=array();
               foreach ($data_final1 as $line123){ 
                    $data_final2[] = $line123['answer_name'];
                }  
             $finaldata1[] = array("fullname"=>$fullname,"email"=>$email,"type"=>$type,"name"=>$name,"data_final2"=>$data_final2 ); 
    
     }
```

Using above code i got below response

Inside the array i have the array, i tried array of array to norml key value response

```
 Array
            (
                [fullname] => John
                [email] => test@gmail.com
                [type] => Admin
                [name] => 
                [data_final2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => IOS 8
                        [1] => Expert 
                        [2] => Sachin
                    )
    
            )
```

But i try to expected below, i tried some other ways it sowing issues or error in php

Expected array

```
Array 

(       
    [fullname] => John
    [email] => test@gmail.com
    [type] => Admin
    [name] => 
    [IOS 8] => IOS 8
    [Expert] =>Expert 
    [Sachin] => Sachin
    )
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting? Also, please try being a bit more specific. What  other ways have you tried?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289475/converting-php-array-of-arrays-into-single-array

Answer (score 1):

```php
// Instead of:
$data_final2[] = $line123['answer_name']; ❌

// Use this:
$data_final2[$line123['answer_name']] = $line123['answer_name']; ✅
```

```php
// Instead of:
 $finaldata1[] = array("fullname"=>$fullname,"email"=>$email,"type"=>$type,"name"=>$name,"data_final2"=>$data_final2 ); ❌

// Use this:
 $finaldata1[] = array_merge(array("fullname"=>$fullname,"email"=>$email,"type"=>$type,"name"=>$name), $data_final2); ✅
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$finaldata = [
    'fullname' => 'John',
    'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'type' => 'Admin',
    'name' => '',
    'data_final1' => [
        'IOS 8','Expert','Sachin',
    ],
];

$data_final2 = [];
foreach($finaldata['data_final1'] as $value){
    $data_final2[$value] = $value;
}
unset($finaldata['data_final1']);
$finaldata = array_merge($finaldata , $data_final2);

print_r($finaldata);
```

The output from this code is

```
Array
(
    [fullname] => John
    [email] => test@gmail.com
    [type] => Admin
    [name] => 
    [IOS 8] => IOS 8
    [Expert] => Expert
    [Sachin] => Sachin
)
```

**Note:** if you're using old php version  use `array()` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like fullname, email, type, and name can be created before the loop and can be assigned to `$finaldata1`.

```
$finaldata1 = compact('fullname', 'email', 'type', 'name');
```

Then looping through `$data_final1` and add both key and value directly to `$finaldata1`

```
foreach ($data_final1 as $line123) {
    $finaldata1[$line123['answer_name']] = $line123['answer_name'];
}
```

So the final code in the loop should look like this.

```
for ($la = 0; $la < count($finaldata); $la++) {
    ...
    ...
    $finaldata1 = compact('fullname', 'email', 'type', 'name');

    foreach ($data_final1 as $line123) {
        $finaldata1[$line123['answer_name']] = $line123['answer_name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$data_final1 = $finaldata['data_final1'];
unset($finaldata['data_final1']);
$finaldata = array_merge($finaldata, array_combine($data_final1,$data_final1));
```